# Use forEach to delete array of object's property failed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's wrong with my code below? how to remove the last two's array of object's name property?

```
let arr = [{id:1,name:'sit'},{id:2,name:'stand'},{id:3,name:'bark'}]

let abc = arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
if(i > 0){
   delete obj.name
}
}))
```

My expected output

```
[{id:1,name:'sit'},{id:2},{id:3}]
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: The code works for me...

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything... you're modifying `arr` in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, works for me, as you can see here.

The only error that I see is that you have an extra `)`.

What you are doing, is modifying the array in place, and foreach doesn't return the new array, as it returns `undefined` instead.

```js
let arr = [{id:1,name:'sit'},{id:2,name:'stand'},{id:3,name:'bark'}]

arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
  if(i > 0){
     delete obj.name
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I would say `undefined` instead of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let arr = [{id:1,name:'sit'},{id:2,name:'stand'},{id:3,name:'bark'}]

        arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
            var index = arr.indexOf(obj);
            if(index > (arr.length - 3)){
                delete obj.name
            }
        })

   console.log(arr)
```